# How to calculate the sum of various columns in a left join?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reporting-services-2012

In SSRS Report Builder 3.0, I have two tables, one is a list of products (with profit) and the other is a list of sold add-ons to the product (with their individual profits).

I am making a report to show each product sold, the profit on the item, the profit on each add on and a total profit.

I am importing the data using this query (additional fields left out for simplicity):

```
SELECT  
  Products.DealID AS DealID  
  ,Profit  
  ,AddonTypeType  
  ,AddOnProfit  
FROM  
  Products  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN productAddOns  
    ON Products.DealID = productAddOns.DealID
```

My table looks like this (note that I do not know ahead of time what the additional Adds will be called or how many there could be):

[image: Current Table]

What is happening is that if a product has two add-ons, it is using the profit twice in the total. In the above screenshot, the first column total should be `108.33 + 843.75= 952.08`, but it is adding in the `843.75` in a second time and showing `1795.83`.

The box for the total is simply using

```
=Sum(CDbl(Fields!Profit.Value))
```

Can anyone help explain why this is happening and how to get it to calculate correctly?

Answer (score 0):

MODIFIED:
Here is an example of a dynamic query that can accommodate a flexible amount of product addons and does not require any hard coding.

```
DECLARE @dynamicSqlPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @columnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @columnName = ISNULL(@columnName + ',',' ')
    + QUOTENAME(addonTypeType) 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT addonTypeType FROM Productaddons) AS prodadds



SET @dynamicSqlPivot = 
N'SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT 

   P.DealID AS dealID
  ,p.Profit 
  ,a.AddonTypeType
  ,a.AddonProfit


FROM  
  Products p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Productaddons a  
    ON P.dealID = A.DealID
    ) AS s


PIVOT (
SUM(s.addonProfit) 
FOR s.addonTypeType IN (' + @columnName + ')) AS pvttable'

EXEC (@dynamicsqlpivot)
```

Comment: I agree that is what is happening, but I don't think I can use your solution. The products can have a theoretically infinite number of Adds and will vary vendor by vendor so I do not have a solid list I can use in that manner. Also, I am pulling more info than just the product and profit.

Comment: A pivot is not going to work in this situation. I end up with an ever changing list of columns that would need to be displayed and no way to select them since I don't know the names ahead of time. Also, I need more information on each product than just the name and total profit.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing (at least until I find a better solution) was to make a query on just the products for just the dealID and make a parameter from that. In the table, I use that parameter to do a MultiLookup and custom code to add all the items in the MultiLookup Object.

`=Code.SumLookup(
    MultiLookup(
        Parameters!DealNumbers.value,
        Fields!DealID.Value,
        Fields!FrontEndGross.Value,
        "CompleteDeals"
    )
)`

An example for the summation was found here: http://salvoz.com/blog/2013/05/27/sum-result-of-ssrs-lookupset-function/